# PowerShell Build a 2D HTML table

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

In my script I've collected all the data I want to report in different variables. Now I'm trying to generate an HTML-table so I can send this by mail.

What I would like to achieve is HTML-code that generates this:

```
OU                 | Logon scripts incorrect | Name incorrect | No description
\\Domain\NLD Users | 2                       | 6              | 2
\\Domain\FRA users | 5                       | 7              | 0
\\Domain\BEL users | 6                       | 1              | 1
TOTAL USERS: 2048  | 13                      | 14             | 3
```

I'm a bit confused on what would be the best approach for this (array, psobject, hashtable, ..).  Because I'm not going to work with a foreach loop, the data would be static.

What I tried so far but isn't quite giving the desired result:

```
$Table = @( ('OU', 'Logon scripts incorrect', 'Name incorrect', 'No description'), 
             ('\\Domain\NLD Users','2','6','2' ),
             ('\\Domain\FRA Users','5','7','0' ),
             ('\\Domain\BEL Users','6','1','1' ),
             ('TOTAL USERS: 2048','13','14','3' )
)    
$Table | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
```

It feels like I'm over-complicating things.

Comment: What about your result so far is not to your liking? Seems like you are doing the right thing. If I can give you any advice it would be to structure your data into a custom object before piping it into ConvertTo-Html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertto-html` is waiting for a psobject as its input.
What you can do is pass your data as csv then use `convertfrom-csv` to tansform it to psobject the run `convertto-html` :

```
$Table = @"                                  
'\\Domain\NLD Users','2','6','2'      
'\\Domain\FRA Users','5','7','0'      
"@                                    

$Table | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'OU', 'Logon scripts incorrect', 'Name incorrect', 'No description' | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table
```

Comment: I was going to send the CSV to file and import it which just seemed silly. Your approach cuts out the middle man nicely and does not involve another loop like mine. Nice.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm going with this one as it seems the cleanest solution. The only thing I had to do to get it fully working was removing the single quotes or there would've been garbage text in the HTML-code.

Answer (score 2):

```
@( ('OU', 'Logon scripts incorrect', 'Name incorrect', 'No description'), 
             ('\\Domain\NLD Users','2','6','2' ),
             ('\\Domain\FRA Users','5','7','0' ),
             ('\\Domain\BEL Users','6','1','1' ),
             ('TOTAL USERS: 2048','13','14','3' )
)  | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        OU = $_[0]
        "Logon scripts incorrect" =  $_[1]
        "Name incorrect" = $_[2]
        "No Description" = $_[3]
    }

} | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
```

From what i have read `ConvertTo-Html` takes .Net Objects and not arrays to convert to html. I converted your static table to a custom object which then was exported. This might look more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an array of arrays with your statement, which looks neat, but isn't something `ConvertTo-Html` can handle. Create new objects instead (this is for v3):

```
$x = @(
    ([pscustomobject] @{
        "OU" = "\\Domain\NLD Users";
        "Logon scripts incorrect" = 2;
        "Name incorrect" = 6;
        "No description" = 2;
    }),
    ([pscustomobject] @{
        "OU" = "\\Domain\FRA Users";
        "Logon scripts incorrect" = 5;
        "Name incorrect" = 7;
        "No description" = 0;
    })
    # ...and so on, or more realistically, constructed using Foreach-Object
)
$x | convertto-html -fragment
```

If you're confined to PowerShell v2, you can use `new-object -type psobject -prop` instead, but then the properties are not ordered so you will need an explicit `Select`.